# Nvidia moduel not found

Tags: nvidia, bumblebee, msi

my laptop has NVidia Optimus and I've been trying to get bumblee to work for weeks.
Installing bumblebee or nvidia-drivers show no errors, I configured it like described in this article: http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Steam#Problembehebung

Yet I get errors running optirun:

```
$ optirun glxspheres 
[142.860483] [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: [XORG] (EE) Failed to load module "nvidia" (module does not exist, 0)

[142.860557] [ERROR]Aborting because fallback start is disabled.
```

Also modprobe tells me this:

```
$ sudo modprobe nvidia
FATAL: Module nvidia not found.
```

But when I try this:

```
lsmod | grep nvidia
nvidia              11309139  0
```

Which is really weird, because lsmod tells me nvidia module is there, while modprobe tells me nvidia cannot be found!

Did anyone have a similar problem and solved it?

Greets

Answer (score 0):

Some of the nvidia compiler/installers seem to fiddle with blacklisting module names in /etc/modprobe.d/ so I'd look in there for some conflicting settings. Such as nvidia being and alias to another module from the one you want to be used.

Comment: As far as I know blacklisting a module only prevents it from being loaded on startup, right? Modprobe should still be possible. Also bumblebee has a blacklist in there blacklisting all nvidia modules because they should not be loaded on startup but by bumblee itself

Comment: Correct, blacklisting does that. But weird things can end up in there with contradictory stuff, so it's worth poking around in modprobe.d to see if anything obviously wrong crept in there somehow.